Structuring a GCP service to restrict access to a cloud run group by incoming hostname
I'm building a service where clients add a JS snippet to their sites. This then communicates with a REST API I host.
The API will be served via a container running on Google Cloud Run.
I plan to put the Run instances behind Cloud Armor, using the SDK to add a rule to Cloud Armor for each clients' hostname, eg:
request.headers['host'].lower().contains('test.example.com')

Any reference I find to a Cloud Armor API (or via gcloud) seems to point to Compute Engine. Am I able to apply a rule to Armor to have it apply to Cloud Run?

You might also be interested in this approach https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/how-to-secure-apis-against-fraud-and-abuse-with-recaptcha-enterprise-and-apigee-x

You don't actually attach the policy directly to the Cloud Run instance (or Compute Engine for that matter); rather, you need to create a Serverless NEG and then attach that Serverless NEG as a Backend Service to the Application Load Balancer. You will attach the Cloud Armor policy to the Backend Service object on the ALB. Keep in mind that you can configure your Cloud Run instance to not use a public end point and it will be restricted to communicate within GCP.
